# Table with merged cells in latex

Tags: tables, alignment

I'm trying to format a table that somehow looks like the picture below.

I am familiar with the `\multirow` operator but this doesn't do the trick for me. Especially the alignment with the Column-Titles and the cells explaining the titles does not work. I'd like to have the subset-signs aligned with the cell borders in the third row.

Also a minor other thing i'm not yet familiar with, is how to force the linebreak within the cells.

I also thought about doing a box-setup somehow but since i'm fairly new to LaTeX i'm a bit lost about the options I have.

[image: This is what i want]

Comment: IMHO you are searching for something like the `b`-columns of [package `array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array). Similar feature is also available with [package `tabularray`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) and [several more tabular packages](https://ctan.org/topic/table). BTW: Please note, that this is not a do-it-for-me page. So it is recommended, to always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) of what you've already tried.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us, what you tray so far. It seems that use `tabularray` package can be promising way to go.

Comment: Any news? Does any of received answer solve your problem? If yoe, please accept it (by clicking on zher check mark at top lef side of answer),. If not, inform us, why exactly you are after.

Answer (score 1):

As starting point (if I guess correctly what is your problem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iwona}      % for sffamily font
\usepackage{microtype}  % for better text spacing
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Z} = {solid}, vline{1-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
             colspec = {*3{X[b,j]}},
             vline{2} = {1}{text=\clap{$\supset$}},
             vline{3} = {1}{text=\clap{$\supset$}},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, c}
             }
CW-Komplex
    &   Deltakompleks
        &   Simplezialkomplex   \\             
\SetCell[c=3]{c, bg=teal!30}    Alle sind konstruierbar durch das Anainnanderheften von Zellen/Simplexen
    &   &   \\
\lipsum[66]
    &   \lipsum[1]
        &   \lipsum[2]
 \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Added symbols `\supset` in the first line and image of table:

[image]

If you like that text in cells are vertically top aligned than change `colspec = {*3{X[b,j]}}` to `colspec = {*3{X[j]}}, i.e. in it remove option` b`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `nicematrix` package which allows you to use Ti*k*Z to place nodes between cells easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.33}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{ X X X }[hvlines, first-row]
    \CodeBefore
        \cellcolor{green!20}{1-}
    \Body
        \Block{1-1}{\textbf{CW-Komplex}} & 
        \Block{1-1}{\textbf{Deltakomplex}} & 
        \Block{1-1}{\textbf{Simplizialkomplex}} \\
        \Block{1-3}{Alle sind konstruierbar durch das Aneinanderheften von Zellen/Simplexen } & & \\
        Als Gregor Samsa eines Morgens aus unruhigen Träumen erwachte, fand er sich in seinem Bett zu einem ungeheuren Ungeziefer verwandelt. & 
        Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken und sah, wenn er den Kopf ein wenig hob, seinen gewölbten, braunen, von bogenförmigen Versteifungen geteilten Bauch, auf dessen Höhe sich die Bettdecke, zum gänzlichen Niedergleiten bereit, kaum noch erhalten konnte. & 
        Seine vielen, im Vergleich zu seinem sonstigen Umfang kläglich dünnen Beine flimmerten ihm hilflos vor den Augen. \\
    \CodeAfter
        \tikz{ \node at (0-1 -| 2) {$\supset$}; \node at (0-2 -| 3) {$\supset$}; }
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

[image]